# Make a web link open App Store on iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, hyperlink, app-store

The question of how to link to a specific app or a list of a specific developers apps from a web link has been answered many times.  My issue is that I cannot find a format that works to open the appstore front page, I do not want to link to a specific app I just want the link to open the app store on iOS devices.  I have tried http://appstore.com and that works on iPad but on the iPhone I am getting a blank page.  Is there a way to open the front page of the app store app from a web link on both iPad and iPhones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thy this:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/en/genre/ios/id36?mt=8"]];`

It opens the featured page at iphone (main page).